# Which RibbonType will show my custom Ribbon for a sent message in Outlook (2013) VSTO Add-In?

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, ribbon

New here so please forgive any faux pas!
I have an `Outlook VSTO Add-in` with a custom ribbon which I currently display only on composing a new message or replying to a message.

I've selected `Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Compose` and `Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Read` in `RibbonType`, and my ribbon appears fine on creating a new message or replying, but not when I go to Sent and open a message.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to where I can find a list of the `RibbonTypes` and what they relate to, or offer any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Read should work fine for the Sent Items folder items. Does it work if you move the problematic message from the Sent Items folder to the INbox folder?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you get a Fluent UI error.

By default, if a VSTO Add-in attempts to manipulate the Microsoft Office user interface (UI) and fails, no error message is displayed. However, you can configure Microsoft Office applications to display messages for errors that relate to the UI. You can use these messages to help determine why a custom ribbon does not appear, or why a ribbon appears but no controls appear. See [How to: Show Add-in user interface errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-show-add-in-user-interface-errors?view=vs-2019) for more information.

You could use any `idMso` value which exists on the compose window and doesn't exist on the read inspector.